# Exception handling using the modal

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

There was such task. 
I have a controller method of removing

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        try { 
            TechnologicalCard technologicalCard = db.TechnologicalCards.Find(id);
            db.TechnologicalCards.Remove(technologicalCard);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = true;
            TempData["message"] = "someMessage";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }          
    }
```

How can I do that would be when an exception is thrown during the removal of the modal appeared with warning text ?

UPDATE

I added the index method

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var id_Head = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        TempData["message"] = "someMessage";
        var technologicalCards = db.TechnologicalCards.Where(c => c.IdHeadDepartment == id_Head).ToList();
        return View(technologicalCards);
    }
```

My view has contains the following code

```
@model IEnumerable<AccountingPlusProject.Models.TechnologicalCard>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Учёт+";
}

<style>
.md-form {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

.img1 {
    background-image: url("/Content/avatars/Head.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 7%;
    height: 65px;
    border-style: none;
    margin-left: 90%;
    margin-top: -8%;
}

.img2 {
    width: 7%;
    height: 65px;
    border-style: none;
    margin-left: 80%;
}

h2 span {
    color: white;
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
}

.demo-card-wide.mdl-card {
    width: 512px;
}

.demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__title {
    color: #fff;
    height: 176px;
}

.demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__menu {
    color: #fff;
}

.container {
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
}

.warningMessage {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: Red;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function () {
    if ($('#myModal').length) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});
</script>



<nav class="navbar navbar-light teal lighten-4" style="height: 100px">
<div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="collapseEx2"   style="margin-top:-2%">
        <img src="~/Content/truelogo.png" style="margin-left:-10%" />
        @Html.ActionLink("Добавить технологическую карту", "Create", null,  new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
        <img src="~/Content/avatars/Head.jpg" class="rounded-circle img-responsive img1">
        @Html.ActionLink("Отмена", "Index", "HeadDepartment", null, new {    @class = "btn btn-danger", @style = "margin-left:100%; margin-top:-11%" })
    </div>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="page-content">
<div class="container">
    @{int i = 1;}
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (i % 4 == 1)
            {
                <tr></tr>
            }
            <td>
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="@item.Image" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <center>
                            <hr />
                            <h4 class="card-title">@item.NameProduct</h4>
                            <hr />
                            @item.Description
                            <hr />
                            @{ var materials = item.SelectedMaterials.ToList();}

                            @foreach (var material in materials)
                            {
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => material.ReferenceMaterial.NameMaterial) <b>&nbsp;Штук:&nbsp;</b>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => material.CountMaterial)
                                <br />
                            }
                            <br />
                            <center>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Настроить материалы", "EditMaterial", new { id = item.IdTechnologicalCard }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
                                <br />
                                @Html.ActionLink("Настроить количество",    "EditCountOfMaterial", new { id = item.IdTechnologicalCard }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
                            </center>
                            <hr />

                            @Html.ActionLink("Удалить", "Delete", new { id =   item.IdTechnologicalCard }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })




                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
                                i++;

                                }
    </table>
</div>
@if (TempData["message"] != null)
{
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                121212  <!--add your message here-->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save   changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
</div>
```

But when I deleting redirects to Index view without modal

Comment: I don't have any idea about asp.net but a good idea about `bootstrap-modal` still want to ask. Does your application or asp.net support rest methods?

Answer (score 0):

> Exception handling using the modal

As you made it clear that you want to show the error in a `modal` window here is what you can do.

You need to again assign this `TempData` data into another `TempData` with in your `Index` method. Since the `TempData` is only alive from one controller to another.

And add this code in your index view.

```
@if (TempData["message"] != null)
{
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        @TempData["message"]   <!--add your message here-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

Then add this script in your `index.cshtml`.

```
$(function(){
 if($('#myModal').length){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
 }
});
```

Comment: How something like this can be done by using the modal?

Comment: @Ovenvan you need to add `@model YourModelType` in your view as first line, and then pass the same model into your view. But I don't think just to pass in a small message using model is a good idea

Comment: Not a model, and a modal

Comment: Could you give me an example Index method?

Comment: @Ovenvan see this post. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/476967/whatplusisplusviewdata-cplusviewbagplusandplustem and in Tempdata section..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass error messages using the model state dictionary as well. In that case, you should be returning the same view back to the user instead of a redirect, so that user can try the action again.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{       
   ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Error! Try again.");
   return View();
}
```

Now make sure you have the Validation helper methods being used in the view to render the error messages from the model state dictionary.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

With this approach, only the `id` will be passed back to the view (*basically read from the model state dictionary*), not all other fields you had. If you want all fields, use the same view model (which your view is strongly typed to) as the method parameter.